# Is it possible to fire a tracking pixel when a user clicks on a link within an external iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dhtml, feed

I've added a Yahoo Stock Chart to my employers corporate web site.

But I now need to fire a tracking pixel when a user clicks on the iframe (and is directed to Yahoo Finance).

The tracking pixel is just a standard 1x1 image.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Here is the page it is on:

http://titanironcorp.com/letter-from-ceo/

(See yahoo stock chart to the right hand side)

And here is the yahoo iframe code:

```
<!-- Start of Yahoo! Finance code -->


<iframe align="right" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://api.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/TFER.OB/badge;chart=5d;quote/HTML/f.white?AppID=kGGnjczXiH7L_1XCo_4qTCp1q_QfckRwmw--&sig=8AwYadBv.K1kUIs0BD6xqpzE6kg-&t=1320612387003" width="300px" height="424px"><a href="http://finance.yahoo.com">Yahoo! Finance</a><br/><a href="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=TFER.OB/">Quote for TFER.OB/</a></iframe>
```

Thanks!
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

You might trying overlaying the whole iframe with a transparent div and putting a tracking pixel on that, but I'd be very, very skeptical it would work (and it would certainly screw up the behavior of the iframe)

Answer (score 0):

For a non-IE solution you can force your event to "useCapture" instead of bubble, which would allow you to put a click event handler on the `iframe` itself.

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture Optional );
```

Per [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener):

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate
>   capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTargets beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed
>   explanation. Note that this parameter is not optional in all browser
>   versions. If not specified, useCapture is false.